# Direct Email Link no need to outlook

Tags: html, email

How can I have a link for submit an email directly? I don't want to use outlook to send email. I want to post email by clicking on submit button without open outlook eexpress and use it.

Comment: are you looking into something like PHP? what do you mean by "clicking on submit button"?

Answer (score 3):

HTML cannot send email directly.  You need server code that can handle a request to send email.  What language are you trying to do this in?

Answer (score 0):

If you use .net, you can look into the namespace system.net.mail.

It is quite easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

You question is not so clear. If all you need is an email to be sent, you could have put a link/button that sends a request to a server CGI to do the job. But of cause, the email will be sent from the server using whatever email user/domain available there.

If you need to have a way to send an email by the *user* from within the browser, I'd say this is a bad idea since it raises a lot security/privacy concerns. In fact, if some javascript (or things alike) does send emails, I'd consider that as a security breach :)